# Windows 10 IoT - REST API deployment

Tags: c#, rest, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

According to the documentation of the Windows 10 IoT REST interface, it is possible to deploy apps via the REST API.

> /api/appx/packagemanager/package
>
> Uploads and installs an .appx file.
>
> HTTP verb: POST
>
> Parameters
>
> package : File name of the package to be installed.
>
> Payload
>
> multi-part conforming http body

How do I assemble the payload correctly? I want to deploy a local .appx package, I tried it this way:

```
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        byte[] filecontent = null;
        string p = storageFolder.Path;
        filecontent = File.ReadAllBytes(p + "\\TestAppDeploy_1.0.1.0_ARM.appx");


        //URL + parameter Base64 encoding
        string filenameb64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TestAppDeploy_1.0.1.0_ARM.appx"));
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/api/appx/packagemanager/package?package="+filenameb64;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        //authentication
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Administrator:password");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new  System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        var multipart = new MultipartContent();
        ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(filecontent);

        multipart.Add(byteArrayContent);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, multipart);

            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var status = response.StatusCode;

            client.Dispose();

            Debug.WriteLine(res + "    " + status);
```

The code is running on the Windows 10 IoT device.

The post action

```
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, multipart);
```

gives me the following response

```
         {"Reason" : "Missing appx file name query parameter"}    BadRequest
```

I guess the Content of the PostAsync call must be a type of MultipartContent with additional parameter/information. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use the HttpClient in the

> System.Net.Http

namespace, to be able to make prober REST calls to the Windows 10 IoT API.

The HttpClient in the

> Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

appears to be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Browser(Chrome, IE)F12 mode - Developer Tools / Network - Upload appx file using browser (minwinpc:8080). See how there POST looks like. (Headers, Response .. etc.)